# Loop show only 1 element

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I'm trying to push elements of a object in a table. So i set up a loop to pus every element of my object. However the loop just does 1 loop.

Ijust did a very basic loop that increment 'i' until it arrive to my data length.

```
getLigneTab : function() {

    var ligne; debugger
    var nbData = ucManager.listData.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < nbData; i++) {  

        ligne = '<tr>' 
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[0].collaborateur+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[0].budget+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[0].consomme+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[0].raf+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[0].nbTicket+'</td>'

        return ligne;
    }       

},
```

I get inside this fonction by the click of a button called "affiche-chiffre" :

```
$('#affichage-chiffre').on("click", function(event) {
        var dateD = $('#debutExport').val();
        var dateF = $('#finExport').val();
        if (dateD == "" && dateD == "") {
            bootbox.alert("Saisissez une période !");
        }
        ucManager.getData(dateD, dateF);
        $('#table').html('');
        $('#table').append(ucManager.getColonnes(dateD, dateF));
        $('#table').append("<tbody></tbody>"); 
        $('#table').find("tbody").append(ucManager.getLigneTab());  
        $('#table').show();
    });
```

I should get a least 7 rows but i only get the first row of the object.

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop, so the function finishes as soon as it encounters it - the first time.

Comment: it is the same results if it's just after the '}'

Comment: @ISSOU you are returning immediately from for loop you are also not using the iteration seed i as well

Comment: `ligne += '<tr>'` and move the `return` down ( after the `}` )

Comment: @Taki also use `listData[i]` instead of `listData[0]`, and there's a missing `</tr>` after the last `</td>`

Comment: oh yes Thanks a lot guys it works ! I did all of this before but never all this changes in the same time. Hollidays kill my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your `getLigneTab` function.

1) Move the `return` statement outside the for loop. That is what is causing it to only execute 1 time.

2) `ucManager.listData[0]` will always access the first element in your array. Change that to `ucManager.listData[i]`.

3) You are setting `ligne` to a new string every time you pass through the loop, so it will only be just a single row once you exit the loop. Use `ligne +=` instead.

4) You are missing the ending `</tr>` tag. Add that to the end of the string for each iteration through the loop.

Your function should now look something like this:

```
getLigneTab : function() {

    var ligne; debugger
    var nbData = ucManager.listData.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < nbData; i++) {  
        ligne += '<tr>' 
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[i].collaborateur+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[i].budget+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[i].consomme+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[i].raf+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+ucManager.listData[i].nbTicket+'</td>'
            + '</tr>';        
    }  
    return ligne;     
}
```